# Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I use the Facebook Graph API without the creation of my Facebook Application? As I understand it, for each operation I need to use the OAuth key. And I can only get user OAuth key if they authorize my Facebook application. Am I right?
I need to get user feed, and post to it.

Comment: Facebook Graph Api needs your APP ID  which you can only get from your Facebook application.  So i think its not possible to post data on facebook without having Application ID.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank everybody for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Graph Api needs your APP ID which you can only get from your Facebook application. So i think its not possible to post data on facebook without having Application ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to dynamically generate an access_token for testing: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Also, check out [RapidAPI here.](https://rapidapi.com/package/FacebookGraphAPI/functions?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=FacebookGraph_FacebookFunctions) I've specifically linked you to the FacebookGraphAPI block. Here you can instantaneously connect to numerous Facebook endpoints. The platform will generate a code snippet that you can directly insert into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do, for most tasks you have to have an app id... but If you want to get the amount of shares for a certain page, for example,  you can do it with no app ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is FBML (facebooks mark up language) which you can embed on your site which can handle some basic tasks like commenting or liking.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't do that as **Facebook Graph API** needs access token which u can get only by authorising your logged-in user by your (Created) App in **Facebook**.