# Error in Search for posts using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am new to this Facebook Graph API. 
I want to search for Facebook posts. 
        https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=post
On the internet I have found the above request and said that it would give me what I want. But when I tried that it asks for the access token. I don't know where to add it. 
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653370/facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can´t search for posts anymore, Public Post Search is deprecated. You can only search for the types specified in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

That being said, you need to create an App to get an Access Token and there are different ones. Please read the docs to find out how to get the different Access Tokens, here are some links for you:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/